# Cabbage rolls question

Tags: food-safety

Can I make cabbage rolls (I use ground beef, rice, seasons, egg and sour cream as the filling) the night before I am going to cook them at 11 the next morning.  Will it be safe?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you chill them quickly and properly you should be ok.

If I remember correctly, the fill must be at least at room temperature when you roll it in the cabbage leaves; and the leaves themselves will also be at room temperature.

So that will cool down nicely in the fridge without stay in the "danger zone" too long.